# How to detect when a user types a string in an input type number?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have a form with an input type number. I want to display a message when the user types a string.
When I try to retrieve the value of the input, I always get an empty string.
When I type a number it works fine but not with a string...
I tried with both jQuery and javascript.

```
        var inputVal = $(this).val();
        var inputValJs = document.getElementById("myInput").value;
        console.log(inputVal); // if 99 => 99   if test => ''
        console.log(inputValJs); // if 99 => 99   if test => ''
```

How should I proceed ?

Comment: Use input type text if both numbers and text should be possible.

Comment: input type number doesnot allow to enter a string

Comment: It should only be numbers. If the user tries to type a string I want to display a message saying 'Only numbers are allowed'.

Comment: If you use a numeric input, the message shouldn't be necessary. But if anyway, you want to show a message, you have two choices: 1 - Use a regular input of type text and treat whatever the user introduce there. 2 - Bind onkeydown event of the numeric input and do the treatement yourself.

Comment: Which browser allows you to enter text but doesn’t assign it to the value? Interesting. It is the case that browsers that do not support the type ‘number’ will fall back to text, but then I would assume value would work.

Answer (score 2):

If you really need an input text you can do the following:

*The event `input` captures the changes in the input text.*

```js
var messageElem = document.querySelector('#myMessage');
document.querySelector('#myInput').addEventListener('input', function(e) {
  if (this.value === '' || /^[0-9]+$/.test(this.value)) {
    messageElem.textContent = "";
  } else {
    messageElem.textContent = "Only numbers";
  }
});
```

```html
<input type="txt" id='myInput'>
<p id='myMessage'>
```

Answer (score 1):

Input type number only allow you to enter numbers

```js
var inputValJs = document.getElementById("myInput").value;
console.log(inputValJs);
```

```html
<input type="number" id="myInput" name="tentacles" value ="33">
```

Comment: Not if the browser falls back to text bc it does not support or enforce this type.

Answer (score 1):

Number type input only accept number value.

To retrieve input value, use event listener :

```js
var myValue = '';

document.getElementById("myInput").addEventListener('input', function(e) {
   myValue = e.target.value;
   console.log(myValue);
});
```

```html
<input type="number" id="myInput">
```